# How to target multiple "li" with same classname

Tags: c#, html, selenium

Hi everyone the function of my code is to take a users shoe size preference and then click on an element on the page based on their size.
I will do this by taking numerical input from the user and store it in a value, then searching for the element that matches the size they have entered.

Here is the html code from the website I am using:

```
<div class="form product__form product__form--size product__form--last js-select-size-mapper">
<ul class = "product-size">
<li class = "js-size-value ">
8
</li>
<li class = "js-size-value ">
9
</li>
<li class = "js-size-value ">
9.5
</li>
<li class = "js-size-value ">
10
</li>
<li class = "js-size-value ">
10.5
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I always get some sort of error regarding how the element is not clickable. The weird part is sometimes the IWebElement declaration is verified (I mean there is no error in declaring it), sometimes there is an error when I try to click.

If you need to see a better example of code, hop over to the website [here](https://shop.adidas.ae/en/energy-boost-atr-shoes/AQ5974.html).

For example, when I run this code:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(@class,'js-size-value ')][contains(text(),size)]"));
            element.Click();
```

*note, I have previously declared a variable called "size", and that's what I'm referring to when it says "(text(),**size**)]"

I get the error:

> Additional information: Unexpected error. Element is not clickable at point (825.1500244140625, 45.69999694824219). Other element would receive the click: div class="header__wrapper">

I don't know how to approach this, and need some light shed on it in general. I have searched through stackoverflow for answers, and haven't found any posts that pertain to exactlty what I am trying to accomplish, or are vague and hard to understand.

Please take caution when answering that I am new to Selenium and C# in general, so if you could add a bit of detail in your answers and not assume I know what you are talking about, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally set size as text instead of as variable. This means selenium will search a list item with the text 'size', which doesn't exist, instead of for example size 9.5,

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(@class,'js-size-value')][contains(text()," + size + ")]"));
```

Comment: Hi Bouke, I ran the code you suggested and a small window popped up saying Firefox was updating... Now I get a "WebDriverException was unhandled" error on the new firefoxdriver() line and firefox will open up but will go to no page. I know it has nothing to do with your code, but do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It might very well be possible WebDriver is not up to date with FireFox. I would suggest to downgrade FireFox to the previous version again or use Chrome for the time being.

Comment: I followed a tutorial and downgraded FireFox. After trying your code, I am getting the error:

Comment: Additional information: Unexpected error. Element is not clickable at point (825.1500244140625, 91.69999694824219). Other element would receive the click: <span></span>

Comment: Does the span overlay the list items? If so, then the items wouldn't be clickable manually either. I would suggest to try Chrome. For future reference: These problems have nothing to do with the initial question.